# Magento 2 swatches problem

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, swatches

I have a very very annoying problem with Magento 2.3.3.
I have a product with size and color attributes.
If I inspect the code, I will see ALL the values:
Indeed in `"Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer":` I will get all the results in `jsonConfig` `jsonSwatchConfig` etc etc.
The problem is that when I click on the attributes, the price doesn't change and the picture doesn't show.

The console is showing me this error `TypeError: this.options.jsonConfig.mappedAttributes is undefined`

On particularly in the `_onClick` function when I call the method `_getAttributeCodeById`.
If I comment the _getAttributeCodeById, the price will update, but the picture will show the magento placeholder.

This thing is driving me crazy!!
Please, help me with that!

Comment: Are you using more than one store view for languages? If so, make sure all the values are filled as I've had issues with swatches for that reason in the past

Comment: No, I have just one store